# CSS combine attribute selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tocolor">tocolor 1
<div id="one">tocolor 11</div>
</div>
<div class="mplampla"><span id="two">
</span>tocolor 2</div>
<div class="tocolor-2"><span id="three">
</span>tocolor 3</div>
<div class="tocolor tocolor-1">tocolor 4 
<span id="one">tocolor 44</span>
</div>
```

and I want to style (let's say color green) "tocolor 11" using a combination of atrribute selectors. 
I tried the following CSS but it doesn't do anything

```
div[class*='tocolor'][div[id*='one']] {
color:green
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Used to this**

```
div[class*='tocolor'] div[id*='one'] {
    color:green
    }
```

**and this**

```
 div[class*='tocolor'] > div[id*='one'] {
        color:green
        }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nd7L8/)**

Comment: that will color me also "tocolor 1" for example. I want to select only "tocolor 11". Thanks

Comment: than used to this >>  div[class*='tocolor'] > div[id*='one'] {
    color:green
    }

Comment: div[class*='tocolor'] div[id*='one'] {
color:green
}